# How to get information about an image (picture) from the Linux command-line?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, command-line-tool

I'm working on a web app and currently migrating some stuff from an old app, but I hate that I have to open an image editor to get some info about images I'm migrating. Things like image dimensions.

Is there a *command line* tool I can use for such tasks in Linux?

Answer (score 374, accepted):

For some image formats you can just use the `file` command:

```
$ file MyPNG.png 
MyPNG.png: PNG image, 681 x 345, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Not all image formats report the size (JPEG most notably doesn't):

```
$ file MyJpeg.jpg 
MyJpeg.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

For those you will have to use something more elaborate, like:

```
$ convert MyJpeg.jpg -print "Size: %wx%h\n" /dev/null
Size: 380x380
```

The `convert` command is part of the ImageMagick package.

Comment: Could just be me but it seems imagemagick is actually loading image data there as it runs pretty slowly. imo `identify` should be used instead

Comment: oh, `/dev/null` is an argument hehe

Comment: FWIW this is what I used to get the creation datetime of a photo:
`identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]\n" foobar.jpg`

Comment: Current version of `file` does support displaying the size of JPEG without additional parameter:
`$ file foo.jpg` returns 
`foo.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 72x72, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=1], baseline, precision 8, 120x120, frames 3`

Answer (score 276):

The best way to get this information is by using the `identify` command:

```
$ identify image.png
```

**or only size attributes**

```
$ identify -format "%wx%h\n" photo.jpg
```

** And if you need **image details**, try the following:

```
$ identify -verbose image.png
```

`identify` is part of `ImageMagick`, which you can install on Ubuntu like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: The specs for the format string can be found in the [GraphicsMagick manual](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-format).

Comment: I will add the `-verbose` flag. I needed to find DPI (that are in the field Resolution)

Comment: for CentOS do: yum install ImageMagick

Comment: This answer both works with jpegs, and gives the information needed to install it.

Comment: +1 for the `-format` option. I needed just the height of a bunch of images, this is great.

Comment: @fbrundu how does DPI relate to a resolution like `72x72`

Comment: Is it possible to show it nicely spaced?  I get the following `595x394597x396592x398595x395594x397822x749842x562`  Very hard to actually read the different image dimensions

Comment: @JohnCrawford To get a list of file names with their resolution, each one on its own line, you can use `identify -format "%f %wx%h\n" *.png`

Comment: This worked best for me for SVG files, e.g. `file` provided: `$ file google-forms.svg google-forms.svg: SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image` while `identify` provided: `$ identify google-forms.svg
google-forms.svg SVG 48x66 48x66+0+0 16-bit sRGB 9543B 0.000u 0:00.006`. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Wow `identify -verbose {.svg file}` is incredibly detailed, if you need more than dimensions and color depth, I'd be surprised if `-verbose` wouldn't provide the info you need.

Comment: There does not appear to be a `-format` for the date create and/or date modified. Have to use verbose :(

Answer (score 45):

exiv2 is "the tool" to get information from picture files:

```
~$exiv2 myimage.jpg
```

outputs:

```
File name       : myimage.jpg
File size       : 1196944 Bytes
MIME type       : image/jpeg
Image size      : 2592 x 1944
Camera make     : LG Electronics
Camera model    : LG-P970
Image timestamp : 2013:05:19 17:27:06
Image number    : 
Exposure time   : 1/9 s
Aperture        : 
Exposure bias   : 0 EV
Flash           : Yes, compulsory
Flash bias      : 
Focal length    : 3.7 mm
Subject distance: 
ISO speed       : 745
Exposure mode   : 
Metering mode   : Average
Macro mode      : 
Image quality   : 
Exif Resolution : 
White balance   : Auto
Thumbnail       : image/jpeg, 13776 Bytes
Copyright       : 
Exif comment    :
```

Comment: do you know when I would get this error from 'exiv2'? Exiv2 exception in print action for file 1059535097558476208.jpg:
Failed to read input data

Comment: Hey Mona Jalal, perhaps it is a faulty image? Have you tried with imagemagick convert/identify yet?

Comment: Was looking for info on SVG files, unfortunately `exiv2` doesn't recognize them: `$ exiv2 google-forms-svgrepo-com.svg 
Exiv2 exception in print action for file google-forms-svgrepo-com.svg:
google-forms-svgrepo-com.svg: The file contains data of an unknown image type`.  `identify` provides brief and useful info, though. `exiv2` looks very useful for other filetypes, though, thank you.

Answer (score 26):

Also, check out [ExifTool by Phil Harvey](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/); an example:

```
$ exiftool test.png 
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.15
File Name                       : test.png
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 12 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:02:13 13:04:52+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : PNG
MIME Type                       : image/png
Image Width                     : 2490
Image Height                    : 3424
Bit Depth                       : 8
Color Type                      : RGB
Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
Filter                          : Adaptive
Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
Significant Bits                : 8 8 8
Image Size                      : 2490x3424
```

Btw, I was looking to get information on dpi/resolution from the command line; and interestingly, sometimes none of these tools report that in an image (like in the above snippet); for more on that, see [I want to change DPI with Imagemagick without changing the actual byte-size of the image data - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/479197/i-want-to-change-dpi-with-imagemagick-without-changing-the-actual-byte-size-of-t) - however, `identify -verbose` seems to work for the same image as in the previous snippet:

```
$ identify -verbose test.png 
Image: test.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2490x3424+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 34.5833x47.5556
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: RGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 8 (0.0313725)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 237.541 (0.931533)
      standard deviation: 37.2797 (0.146195)
      kurtosis: 21.2876
      skewness: -4.56853
    Green:
      min: 15 (0.0588235)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 240.007 (0.941204)
      standard deviation: 37.8264 (0.148339)
      kurtosis: 20.7241
      skewness: -4.51584
    Blue:
      min: 9 (0.0352941)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 240.349 (0.942547)
      standard deviation: 38.7118 (0.151811)
      kurtosis: 22.255
      skewness: -4.72275
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 8 (0.0313725)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 179.474 (0.703821)
      standard deviation: 108.711 (0.426316)
      kurtosis: -0.958865
      skewness: -0.995795
  Rendering intent: Undefined
  Interlace: None
  Background color: white
  Border color: rgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 2490x3424+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2014-02-13T13:11:08+01:00
    date:modify: 2014-02-13T13:04:52+01:00
    signature: bada990d3ba29b311501146d9013d67cf36f667c6d39b1f28a72ce913924397d
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 12.52MB
  Number pixels: 8.526M
  Pixels per second: 7.894M
  User time: 1.080u
  Elapsed time: 0:02.080
  Version: ImageMagick 6.6.2-6 2012-08-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

... although, it can be a bit tricky to read resolution in units of PixelsPerInch using `identify -verbose` - see [ImageMagick • View topic - Cannot set units to pixelsperinch?](http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=24980&p=107919&sid=313efe3a564273d433558e46c8877254#p107919).

Comment: Nice: `identify -verbose` is the only tool I found that reports JPG quality. For example it will say `Quality: 90`.

Comment: `identify -verbose` reports something called "*pixels per second*" measured in ... **MB**! This scares me off a bit ;).

Answer (score 23):

[mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) would give even more detailed info. It is usually in the standard repos on Linux, and also available via homebrew on OSX.

Try for example running in the current folder:

```
mediainfo *
```

or

```
mediainfo .
```

Both commands will show info on all media files in the current folder and subfolders.

Show info on all JPG images starting from current folder (includes subfolders):

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -exec mediainfo {} \;
```

It can also be useful with audio and video files as it shows the bitrate of all audio/video streams, encoding algorithm, container type, FOURCC code, i.e. `XVID`, `X264`, etc.

There is also a GUI available in standard repos for all major distros usually named `mediainfo-gui`

Answer (score 20):

```
identify -verbose image.png
```

identify is from the ImageMagick package.

It also extract exif informations from jpeg image.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this command if above answers don't work:

```
rdjpgcom -verbose photo.jpg
```

It will show info like:

**JPEG image is 564w * 779h, 3 color components, 8 bits per sample**

Answer (score 7):

I just discovered that less (with lessfile/lesspipe) can actually display image info by using ImageMagick behind the scene:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
less wallpaper.jpg
```

Output

```
wallpaper.jpg JPEG 1920x1200 1920x1200+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 580KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: Is this a joke?  I tried this, and it popped up a warning asking me if I really want to read a binary file, and then it just displayed a bunch of binary... (using Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: You need to install ImageMagick for it to work. I mentioned that it uses ImageMagick behind the scene, didn't I?

Comment: Quite a dumb way of doing it ...  if you have imageMagick installed just use identify command.

Comment: Installing ImageMagick has no effect on the output of less.

Answer (score 7):

Other method not posted above, is using feh (you need to install it):

```
feh -l image.jpg
```

Output:

```
NUM FORMAT  WIDTH   HEIGHT  PIXELS  SIZE(bytes) ALPHA   FILENAME
1   jpeg    1280    960     1228800 91319       -       image.jpg
```

Using:

```
feh -l *.jpg
```

Will output a table (as above) but with all images information (incrementing the NUM column). Useful to use in scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The tool you want is `file`.

It shows a surprising amount of info about all sorts of files.

The syntax is:

`$ file my_pic.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
php -r "print_r(getimagesize('file:///archives/Picture/12 farvardin/20120331_013.jpg'));"
```

Also you can replace `file://` with `http://`

Comment: Piggy backing on this you can do the same thing, but using command line args to make it a little easier to use.

`php -r "print_r(getimagesize(\$argv[1]));"`

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with PNGs, there might be attributes that I've found difficult to read with almost any software. For those, you should use pngmeta:

> pngmeta file.png

That's particularly useful for thumbnails, since, according to FreeDesktop standard, should be PNG formatted and store path information as a PNG attribute (Thumb::URI).

Comment: not telling any dpi in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

As provided in the rest of the answers you can use `identify` command with `-verbose` flag.

Below is a way to **select specific information** from the `identify` output, which is (almost) `yaml` format.

```bsh
sudo pip install yq
# OR
pip install --user yq


# note: sed is used to remove what breaks yaml format (first line only).   
identify -verbose image.png | sed 's/^Image:.*/Image:/' \
  | yq -Y '.Image|{"Format","Geometry","Colorspace","Depth","Channel depth","Filesize","Number pixels"}'
```

**output:**

```
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Geometry: 1000x714+0+0
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
  red: 8-bit
  green: 8-bit
  blue: 8-bit
Filesize: 125KB
Number pixels: 714K
```

**json output (without -Y flag):**

```
{
  "Format": "JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)",
  "Geometry": "1000x714+0+0",
  "Colorspace": "sRGB",
  "Depth": "8-bit",
  "Channel depth": {
    "red": "8-bit",
    "green": "8-bit",
    "blue": "8-bit"
  },
  "Filesize": "125KB",
  "Number pixels": "714K"
}
```

> Note: tesed with `.jpg` `.png` `.gif`,`.tif`. Also does not seem to work with `.svg` (`identify` output is differrent)

Answer (score 0):

With *GraphicsMagick*:

```
# for minimal information
gm identify some-image.png

# for detailed information
gm identify -verbose some-image.png
```