# Find out information about creator of a file(mp4,jpeg)

Tags: mp4, jpeg, media-info

I recently got an email(spam) attachment with several images(jpeg) and one video (mp4). For curiosity I want to find out who really made these things and potentially find out whom actually sent the spam email.

From inspecting the file on Mac didn't give me much information other than about the file itself.

I ran `mediainfo -f` on Linux, but all I got was "just" detailed information on the file. Nothing about the source creator.

For video mp4 I couldn't [find any information](http://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/mp4-layout.txt) about such information(creator info) being able to exist in the file.
Neither on jpeg was I able to [find information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) about that "creator info" can exist in the file.

Q: Does source information exists in these files(whom made the file)?

Q: How can I go about extracting more information out of the files?

EDIT:

I tried following commands:

```
identify -verbose filename.jpg
identify -format "%[EXIF:*]" filename.jpg
```

I don't get any relevant info. I think EXIF information mentioned in the comments must be removed. I'm out of ideas..

Comment: It can but could just as well be removed. For `jpeg` you should look at the EXIF information if it has anything.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/275502/how-to-get-information-about-an-image-picture-from-the-linux-command-line, http://fotoforensics.com/

Comment: Thanks. I tried the 'identity -verbose' command from imagemagick package.  Only displayed file details. The exif information doesn't seem to exist, it should have been displayed on the 'identity -verbose' command, am I right?